# Array looping with numbers along with key or value in TCL for Report structure

Tags: arrays, loops, report, tcl

I need to print a report with dynamic row and dynamic columns as like below.

```
            apple                           bannana                  pineapple
    Total           47              Total           376             Total 210
    a       :       3               i       :       10              m       : 45
    b       :       4               j       :       33              o       : 67
    c       :       18              k       :       245             n       : 98
    d       :       22              l       :       45
                                    x       :       43
```

I thought to take the llength of all the list and iterate the for loop with
the highest llength of the list. In the above example it is 5 times.

My doubt is, how I can print the particular pair in the list with the number I
get from the "for loop".

For example, In the first iteration, I need to select the first item of all
the fruits and print. May be like fruit_${type}[1]. Not sure how I can do.
Please advise.

```
    #!/bin/sh
    # \
    exec tclsh "$0" "$@"
    set fruit_apple {{a 3} {b 4} {c 18} {d 22}}
    set fruit_bannana {{i 10} {j 33} {k 245} {l 45} {x 43}}
    set fruit_pineapple {{m 45} {o 67} {n 98}}
    set fruit {apple bannana pineapple}
    puts $fruit_apple
    foreach type $fruit {
    puts $type
            foreach pair [set fruit_${type}] {
                    set key [lindex $pair 0]
                    set value [lindex $pair 1]
                    puts "$key : $value"
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do a lot of work to format a report vertically like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env tclsh
set fruit_apple {{a 3} {b 4} {c 18} {d 22}}
set fruit_bannana {{i 10} {j 33} {k 245} {l 45} {x 43}}
set fruit_pineapple {{m 45} {o 67} {n 98}}
set fruit {apple bannana pineapple}
set maxl [expr {max([llength $fruit_apple], [llength $fruit_bannana], [llength $fruit_pineapple])}]

set fmt "%s\t%s\t%s\t"
foreach type $fruit {
    puts -nonewline [format $fmt "" $type ""]
    set total($type) 0
    foreach pair [set fruit_${type}] {
        lassign $pair key value
        incr total($type) $value
    }
}
puts ""
foreach type $fruit {
    puts -nonewline [format $fmt Total "" $total($type)]
}
puts ""
for {set i 0} {$i < $maxl} {incr i} {
    foreach type $fruit {
        set pair [lindex [set fruit_$type] $i]
        if {[llength $pair] == 2} {
            puts -nonewline [format $fmt [lindex $pair 0] : [lindex $pair 0]]
        } else {
            puts -nonewline [format $fmt "" "" ""]
        }
    }
    puts ""
}
```

output:

```
        apple                   bannana                 pineapple               
Total           47      Total           376     Total           210     
a       :       3       i       :       10      m       :       45      
b       :       4       j       :       33      o       :       67      
c       :       18      k       :       245     n       :       98      
d       :       22      l       :       45                              
                        x       :       43
```

It's marginally easier to transform your data into better data structures. Here, using arrays:

```
#! /usr/bin/env tclsh
set fruit_apple {{a 3} {b 4} {c 18} {d 22}}
set fruit_bannana {{i 10} {j 33} {k 245} {l 45} {x 43}}
set fruit_pineapple {{m 45} {o 67} {n 98}}
set fruit {apple bannana pineapple}

array set keys {}
array set values {}
array set total {}
set maxl 0
foreach type $fruit {
    set l [set fruit_$type]
    if {[llength $l] > $maxl} {set maxl [llength $l]}
    set total($type) 0
    foreach pair $l {
        lassign $pair key value
        lappend keys($type) $key
        lappend values($type) $value
        incr total($type) $value
    }
}

set fmt "%s\t%s\t%s\t"
foreach type $fruit {
    puts -nonewline [format $fmt "" $type ""]
}
puts ""
foreach type $fruit {
    puts -nonewline [format $fmt Total "" $total($type)]
}
puts ""
for {set i 0} {$i < $maxl} {incr i} {
    foreach type $fruit {
        if {$i < [llength $keys($type)]} {
            puts -nonewline [format $fmt [lindex $keys($type) $i] : [lindex $values($type) $i]]
        } else {
            puts -nonewline [format $fmt "" "" ""]
        }
    }
    puts ""
}
```